# What is the least dangerous way to allow users to enter code samples?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, sql-injection

I'm implementing a Rails application in which users will be able to store snippets of code for later reference. I'm planning to use Markdown for text entry and will probably use the [wmd markdown editor](http://wmd-editor.com/). (The very one Stackoverflow uses.)

I'm a little concerned about the idea of people entering code into the edit box. From what I understand, there's a danger of entering SQL that could screw up my DB, or of entering JavaScript that would get run later and do mischief.

Ordinarily, Rails has functionality to guard against this, but am I in a special situation here because my users will be encouraged to enter snippets of code?

Are there any extra precautions I should be aware of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just sanitize your DB entries and you'll be ok. Rails does that by default now. You just have to use the framework correctly. Check this out for more informations: http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/howtos/security/sql_injection

DO THIS:

```
Project.find(:all, :conditions => ["name = ?", params[:name]])
# or
Project.find(:all, :conditions => {:name => params[:name]})
```

NOT THIS:

```
Project.find(:all, :conditions => "name = '#{params[:name]}'")
```

You also have to prevent XSS attacks by going

```
<%=h possible_harmful_text %>
```

For reference:

> Cross-site scripting (XSS) is a type
>   of computer security vulnerability
>   typically found in web applications
>   which allow code injection by
>   malicious web users into the web pages
>   viewed by other users. Examples of
>   such code include client-side scripts.
>   An exploited cross-site scripting
>   vulnerability can be used by attackers
>   to bypass access controls such as the
>   same origin policy. Vulnerabilities of
>   this kind have been exploited to craft
>   powerful phishing attacks and browser
>   exploits. Cross-site scripting carried
>   out on websites were roughly 80% of
>   all documented security
>   vulnerabilities as of 2007. Often
>   during an attack "everything looks
>   fine" to the end-user who may be
>   subject to unauthorized access, theft
>   of sensitive data, and financial
>   loss.
>   ([via wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting))

and of course

> SQL injection is a code injection
>   technique that exploits a security
>   vulnerability occurring in the
>   database layer of an application. The
>   vulnerability is present when user
>   input is either incorrectly filtered
>   for string literal escape characters
>   embedded in SQL statements or user
>   input is not strongly typed and
>   thereby unexpectedly executed. It is
>   an instance of a more general class of
>   vulnerabilities that can occur
>   whenever one programming or scripting
>   language is embedded inside another.
>   SQL injection attacks are also known
>   as SQL insertion attacks.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)
>   ([via wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection))

Comment: From Wikipedia, I take it? ;)

Answer (score 3):

You're not in a special situation because users will be encouraged to enter snippets of code. People can enter snippets of code in fields where they're not encouraged to. Basically, you should always be "extra careful". Don't trust user input.

Answer (score 2):

You're actually in a safer position in accepting code *samples* rather than allowing *actual* code. By that I mean, e.g. Stack Overflow lets me enter actual HTML to control my post.

Allowing actual code is **much** more dangerous, because you'll be evaluating that code. In the Stack Overflow example, the site is actually evaluating input markup like `<a href="http://example.com/">link</a>` -- which means it needs to be on the lookout for onclick handlers, etc. Thorough sanitization is much tougher than simply escaping.

So as long as you're not evaluating anything, you're in the same boat as any other site that accepts text input. Stick to the standard data input principles -- e.g. escape any and all input immediately before writing it anywhere -- and you'll be fine.